# use ng-repeat to show 2 elements in one go

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm required to create something like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <div class="col">
<div>
```

Now i have array having 6 elements.. 
So, i need to create something like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"> 1 </div>
  <div class="col"> 2 </div>
<div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col"> 3 </div>
   <div class="col"> 4 </div>
<div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col"> 5 </div>
   <div class="col"> 6 </div>
<div>
```

I'm not getting how to do this.. 
What i had tried..

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="a in elem">
      <div class="col"> {{a.name}} </div>
      <div class="col"> {{a.name}} </div>
<div>
```

but, this is giving same values..in both ..

Comment: I suggest you split your array before hand in pairs of 2, and then simply use 2 ng-repeats. One for row, and other for col. This makes it dynamic for any situation

Comment: @AndrewDonovan yes.. this will work. Alternatively, just curious to know..  Is it possible to show 2 consecutive elements in one loop of ng-repeat ..  ?

Comment: If it is wrapped yes. Ng-repeat repeats the element it is on, and anything within. But i'm sure you knew that. Therefor, printing 2 *sibling* elements is not possible (with the same ng-repeat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to do some hack with angular you could use flexbox:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">Col 1</div>
  <div class="col">Col 2</div>
  <div class="col">Col 3</div>
  <div class="col">Col 4</div>
  <div class="col">Col 5</div>
  <div class="col">Col 6</div>
</div>
```

It has the advantage that you can make a responsive design much easier than with a fixed number of columns with angular.

Comment: Big thanks brother.. Great approach though ..! I was struggling from like 2 hours..

Answer (score 1):

Updated

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="a in elem" ng-if="$even">
        <div class="col"> {{elem[$index - 1].name}} </div>
        <div class="col"> {{a.name}} </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: No.. 6 is just for example.. The size is unknown.. I need to know how to  print 2 consecutive elements in one loop ..